# Query update except latest data on same conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario to update the rows 
within the same condition(status = 1) but not the latest row.
So this is the table design.

```
--------------------------------------------------
|idx     | status | var1  |  date
--------------------------------------------------
| 2      |  1     |  cat  | 2018-06-17 15:41:32.110      
| 3      |  1     |  dog  | 2018-06-17 11:41:32.110
| 2      |  1     |  lamb | 2018-06-17 11:41:32.110
| 2      |  1     |  pc   | 2018-06-17 09:41:32.110
| 3      |  1     |  doll | 2018-06-17 09:41:32.110
```

What I want is to get all the same conditions
where idx is equal and status = 1, and 
update the status to 0 except the most recent row.
In this case, there are 3 rows which have idx of 2 and status = 1,
and 2 rows which have idx of 3 and status = 1.
After the query, the table should look like this

```
--------------------------------------------------
|idx     | status | var1  |  date
--------------------------------------------------
| 2      |  1     |  cat  | 2018-06-17 15:41:32.110      
| 3      |  1     |  dog  | 2018-06-17 11:41:32.110
| 2      |  0     |  lamb | 2018-06-17 11:41:32.110
| 2      |  0     |  pc   | 2018-06-17 09:41:32.110
| 3      |  0     |  doll | 2018-06-17 09:41:32.110
```

I have no idea how to do this and tried to at least display
the rows which has more than 1 equal conditions and came up with this query

```
select Idx, status, COUNT(Idx) as count from table 
group by Idx, status
having COUNT(Idx) > 1 and status = 1
order by Idx
```

This shows how many rows I have in the same condition,
but I would also like to have rows to display var1 and date
but I don't know how to do that.

As I am working in a .Net development, I could make a list of idx
to a list and do a for loop on each idx and update in that for loop,
but I would love to learn more about sql, how to solve this through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try updating with a CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY idx ORDER BY date DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

UPDATE cte
SET status = 0
WHERE rn > 1 AND status = 1;
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what is CTE? Is this just a variable name?

Comment: cte refers to common table expression, you can call it what you like...for instance `With Sales_CTE...`

Comment: @JinmoChong CTE stands for _common table expression_.  It is basically a way to un-inline SQL code.  So, when you run the above update, the CTE basically gets inlined.

Comment: Wow this works! I can vaguely understand how it is happening but would never come up this my self.

Comment: @JinmoChong This is what Stack Overflow is for, and in fact I also didn't know this trick until I started using the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve it without the CTE:

```
UPDATE t SET status = 0 FROM tbl t WHERE NOT EXISTS 
( SELECT 1 FROM tbl GROUP BY idx HAVING MAX(date)=t.date AND idx=t.idx );
```

see here: http://rextester.com/BVAS22315

The difference between Tim's and my solution would be that in case of two records with the same `idx` having exactly the same date, Tim's command would leave only one record unchanged (`status=1`) while my command would keep them both unchanged.

And, using the window function `ROW_NUMBER()`, you can also do it like this:

```
UPDATE t SET status=0 FROM 
  (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY idx ORDER BY date DESC) rn 
   FROM tbl) t 
WHERE rn>1
```

This second version will behave exactly like Tim's solution, see here: http://rextester.com/MFRAMR93418
(Note the identical dates for 'dog' and 'lamb' and only one gets updated.)